# made my own forEach function in javascript, but it's returning undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

Part of a Javascript course that I'm taking, you're supposed to create your own forEach function that takes two arguments, an array and a callback. It's supposed to pass to the callback each element, its index, and the array itself. Should return undefined. Here is mine:

```
function myForEach (arr, cb) {
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var elem = arr[i];

    cb(elem, i, arr);
  }
}
```

Then, you're supposed to reference it in another function and use that to execute some example functions. Particularly, you're supposed to write a function that accepts an array and a callback as arguments and it should pass the callback to every element, its corresponding index, and the array itself. And then it should return a new array where each element in the new array is the return value of the callback. Here is the function in question:

```
function myMap(arr, cb) {
  var mapped = [];

  mapped.push(myForEach(arr, cb));

  return mapped;
}
```

I don't understand why (in this example), I'm getting undefined as my value, when the callback being passed should be returning a value:

```
console.log(myMap([1, 2, 3], function(ele, i, arr){
  return ele * i;
}));
// [0, 2, 6] expected return value
```

Generally just a bit confused here on balancing what's returning undefined vs. what isn't, and how to actually push a value from the callback into my empty array.

Comment: your forEach doesn't return anything, so that's the same as `return undefined`

Comment: The problem is with this line 

    mapped.push(myForEach(arr, cb));

myForEach doesn't return every item, that goes into the callback (in fact it returns nothing which is why you get undefinfed).  Here's how to make it work, invoke cb manually and then push it to the mapped array. Like so : https://jsfiddle.net/2htuer9m/

Comment: "*it should pass the callback to every element*" - I don't think so :-)

Comment: @HattanShobokshi ahhh yes - I went over this with a coworker and he also pointed out that you have to run a function as the cb for myForEach that pushes the values to your empty array, and the values you're pushing are just the values of the cb being passed to myMap.

Comment: Like this`function myMap(arr, cb) {
  var mapped = [];

  myForEach(arr, function(ele, i, arr) {
    mapped.push(cb(ele, i, arr));
  });

  return mapped;
}`

Answer (score 0):

There's something about this line:

```
mapped.push(myForEach(arr, cb));
```

You're just adding an 'undefined' value (that's what the 'myForEach' function returns) to an empty array.

Comment: Yeah I figured it out - knowing that myForEach is returning undefined. You can see my comment above for the revision. Basically had to switch some callbacks and embed the `.push()` function in between them.

Answer (score 0):

The `.push()` is currently receiving its value directly from `myForEach()`, which doesn't contain a `return` statement to provide a value (so, it returns `undefined` by default).

Being in between the `cb` and `.push()`, `myForEach()` is receiving the results of each `cb()` and discarding them rather than providing them to `myMap()`.

To avoid that, you'll want move the steps so the `.push()` and `cb()` are immediately tied to each other:

```
mapped.push(cb(elem, i, arr));
```

You can still use `myForEach()`, moving it instead around this to perform the iteration, so each `elem` can be processed by `cb` and pushed to `mapped`:

```
function myMap(arr, cb) {
  var mapped = [];

  myForEach(arr, function (elem, i, arr) {
    mapped.push(cb(elem, i, arr));
  });

  return mapped;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The callback to `map` and `forEach` is "what should I do with each element" - and you're not doing the same thing in `myMap`'s each element as in `myForEach`'s each element.

Inside `myMap`, you want to do this: For each element of `arr`, *call the `myMap`'s callback, then push the result into the result array.* (the emphasized part is the `myForEach` callback you need to use every time for `myMap` to function).

Meanwhile, if you want to map `[1, 2, 3]` to `[0, 2, 6]`, the `myMap` callback is saying `multiply each element with its index and return that value`. So you absolutely need two different callbacks.

In short,

> `myForEach(arr, function(element, i, ary) { mapped.push(cb(element, i ary)); });`

Comment: @david25272: Yeah, that was not well put.

Answer (score 0):

The terminology of the map-callback paradigm can be a bit confusing at first.

The map method (e.g. Array.map()) is not the mapping function/callback.  It's a loop that applies a callback function to each item of an array.

The callback does the mapping - it maps (or translates) an array *item* into another value.

So, your callback() function should be taking a single array item (not an array) as an argument, and returning an array item.  The map function calls the callback for each item in the array, and assembles the result into a new array.  (Alternately, it could return an object, or alter the original array in place).

For example:

```
var mymap = function(array, callback) {
    var rv = [];
    for(var i=0; i < array.length ; i++) {
        rv.push(callback(array[i]));
    }
    return rv;
}

mycopy = function(element) {
    return element;
}
```

Then you can use map to duplicate an instance of MyArray:

```
var oldarray = [...];

var newarray = mymap(oldarray, mycopy);
```

The point of all this is that you can easily replace `mycopy()` with something more useful, including functions defined elsewhere or inline anonymous functions:

```
var positives = mymap(oldarray, Math.abs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your issue.

```
console.log(myMap([1, 2, 3], function(ele, i, arr){
  return ele * i;
}));
```

In the second parameter you are trying to pass an anonymous function. You cannot do this this way due to the hoisting process. Plus there aren't any passed to to this function before it gets executed so it returns undefined.